# Git: How to push dist directory to a separate branch of the same repository

Tags: git, deployment, gulp, gitlab, git-branch

I have a project in existing repository, the folder structure :

```
myproject (master)
+-- app/ (master)
+-- dist/ (in .gitignore, but i need it as other branch)
+-- node_modules (.gitignore)
+-- index.html (master)
+-- gulpfile.babel.js (master)
+-- package.json (master)
```

Is there a way to push `dist` to a separate branch of the same repository?
To clarify, I want only `dist` files in the `deploy` branch, and keep the another files in the `master`.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way to push `dist` to a separate branch of the same repository?

There is, using [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

- create an [orphan branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout---orphanltnewbranchgt) '`deploy`'
- copy your `dist` folder content in the empty repo, add and commit, and push.
- add that branch as a `dist` folder submodule.

That is:

```
git checkout --orphan deploy
# copy your folder content
git add .
git commit -m "deploybranch folder content"
git push -u origin deploy
```

Then

```
git checkout master
git submodule add -b deploy -- /remote/url/of/your/own/repo dist
git commit -m "Add deploy branch as submodule"
git push
```

In your `master` branch, you will keep a reference to `deploy` through the `dist` root folder submodule.

That being said, keep in mind what is generated and deployed is usually *not* stored in a *source* control file system, but in a binary referential like [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype) or [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/): make sure you don't keep huge binaries in there.

Comment: thanks for answering my question, when i add deploy branch as submodule, it said `The following path is ignored by one of your .gitignore files: dist`
`Use -f if you really want to add it.` should i remove `/dist` folder from `.gitignore` ? doesn't it `/dist` will pushed to `master branch` ? do you have a solution for this?

Comment: @vanio178 Simply remove dist from your .gitignore file: you don't need to ignore that folder anymore.

Comment: sorry for asking your help again, but now it said : `repo URL: 'deploy' must be absolute or begin with ./|../` @VonC

Comment: @vanio178 on which  command? git submodule add? you must use the remote remo URL.

Comment: yes @VonC , it was in command `git submodule add` . i think my remote url format isn't correct yet ? `git submodule add -b -f deploy -- https://gitlab.com/<company>/<project>/myproject-web.git/dist(branch name)/dist`

Comment: You need to stop at .git for the URL